# Do data-only SIM cards have a phone number assigned to them?

Tags: sim-card

Some providers offer a "data only" sim card. Do these types of sim cards have a phone number assigned to them? If yes, what happens if a dial out is attempted of if there's an incoming call?

Answer (score 5):

A number has to be assigned so that the (rather old) system can recognise the SIM.

Just because it has a number though doesn't mean that any calls can be made or received and will already have been disabled by the network.

The provider can add services as wanted/needed though: SMS can be useful for [managing routers](http://www.draytek.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=5765:how-to-command-vigor-lte-router-by-sms-message?&lang=en).

Comment: in my country data-only SIMs can send and receive SMSes. Some provider even allows a normal sim to be converted to a data SIM

Comment: Indeed it's up to the provider what they want to provide.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, they have. Usually, "data-only SIM" only have a special tariff plan with cheap data service rates, and is an ordinary SIM from all other points of view.

Finally, it fully depends on cellular provider - it can allow voice services, or it can prohibit them.

So, the only way to get a correct answer is to try.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they do have number, perhaps, *special* number, taken from a specialized pool of numbers, allocated for certain purposes, such as assigning tailored tariff plan to them.

You might hear of "Numberless" sim cards [in some parts of the world](http://mybroadband.co.za/news/cellular/8152-mtn-numberless-sim-system.html), however, these sim cards aren't entirely numberless. You'll **need** a number to actually use it.